# Is there a power manager for text consoles?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, power-management, virtual-consoles

I use XFCE on my laptops. When I'm working inside X11,  `xfce4-power-manager` works well, and the system goes to sleep after 15 minutes of inactivity.

But when I switch to a Linux text VT (i.e. by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`) the power manager is unaware of my operations there, and put the system into sleep mode even when I'm still working.

Of course I could turn off the power manager to prevent all sleeps, but I do want the power saving features.
Is there any way to fix this, or should I disable `xfce4-power-manager` and find a VT-aware equivalent?